# Как вернуть 2 значения? (PYTHON)

Tags: python

У меня есть такой код, я хочу вернуть 2 значения `True` и `nick`, но вот еще, возможно ли при вызове функции выбрать значение, которое хочешь вернуть (например `True`)

```
 def c_nick(id_user):
     with open('nicks.txt') as json_file:
         data = json.load(json_file)
         for i in data['users']:
             if i['id'] == int(id_user):
                 nick = i['nick']
                 return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно как-то так сделать:

```
def c_nick(id_user, ret: ('both', 'bool', 'nick') = 'both'):
    with open('nicks.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for i in data['users']:
            if i['id'] == int(id_user):
                nick = i['nick']
                match ret:
                    case 'both':
                        return (True, nick)
                    case 'bool':
                        return True
                    case 'nick':
                        return nick
```

Примеры:

```
c_nice(id_, 'both') # (True, nick)
c_nice(id_, 'bool') # True
c_nice(id_, 'nick') # nick
```

Comment: а не подскажите, как выбрать вызвать функцию с case 'nick ?

Comment: @fixees__ добавил примеры.